# Model won't update on submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im getting this weird error when i want to update my model (model name carts).
Error : **The action 'update' could not be found for CartsController**

this is my `carts_controller.rb` :

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
    include CartForcable
    before_action :scoped_cart, only: [:show, :update]

    def show
    end

    private

    def scoped_cart
        force_cart! lambda {|r| r.includes(:entries => {:sign => [:dimensions, :substrates]})}
    end


def update
        @cart = @cart.find(params[:id])
        if @cart.update_attributes(cart_params)
            flash[:notice] = translate 'flash.notice'
        else
            flash[:error] = translate 'flash.error'
        end
        support_ajax_flashes!
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # renders view
            format.json { render json: @entry }
        end
    end
end
```

and these are my `routes.rb` :

```
resources :categories, only: [:index] do
            resources :signs, shallow: true, only: [:index]
        end

        resources :carts, only: [:show, :update]#, param: :cart_permalink

        resource :cart, as: :user_cart, only: [:show, :update], param: :cart_permalink do
            resources :cart_entries, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy], as: 'entries', path: 'entries'
        end
        resource :user, only: [:edit, :show, :update], as: 'current_user', path: 'profile'

        resources :signs, only: [:show]

        resources :pages, only: [:show], param: :permalink
```

and my `show.html.erb` has this form :

```
<%= form_for @cart, :url => {:controller => "carts", :action => "update" } do |f| %>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>
            <%= f.label :regnum %>
            <%= f.text_field :regnum %></br>

        <%= button_to "Order/update", {:controller => "carts",:action =>
        'update', :id => @cart.id }, :method => :update %>
        <% end %>
```

After i enter name or number (for example), and click update button or something, it doesnt upload any data into model carts(which has the right columns).

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: you don't need to specify the route on the button tag, you already have that on the form action, just use a button or submit tag with value "Order/update"

Comment: @arieljuod i get same error for both buttons(either submit or button tag) **Couldn't find Cart without an ID**

Answer (score 2):

Your `update` method is private; controller actions need to be public.  Move

```
def update
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

to be above the

```
private
```

line.  You need to do the find on the `Cart` model, not a `@cart` instance.

You can use a show action although `edit` would be more standard and fits right in with the RESTful routes without the need to override convention.  The Rails routing guide should help here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Additionally, you need to define the value of `@cart` in your edit action:

```
def edit
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end
```

This will ensure it has a value on the edit form and so comes back into your update action through the parameters.

So if you try to edit a cart with something like `/carts/12345/edit` (where 12345 is the id of the cart you want to update) it should all hang together.

Comment: now i get this error `undefined method `find' for #<Cart:0xb4d4bf20>`

Comment: even after i change `show` to `edit` and add `@cart = Cart.find(params[:id])` i get error like : **Couldn't find Cart without an ID** :/

Comment: What do you mean? what should i put there exactly in `def edit end`

Comment: Done, i get the logic behind it, but somehow i still get the error message **Couldn't find Cart without an ID**

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong:

```
@cart = @cart.find...
```

don't you mean...?:

```
@cart = Cart.find...
```

And it seems you are using "cart_permalink" instead of "id" on your routes

```
resource :cart, as: :user_cart, only: [:show, :update], param: :cart_permalink do
```

Check the server log and see the name of the parameter that holds the ID, also run "bundle exec rake routes" to double check.

Comment: these are the routes for edit ` edit_user_cart GET        (/:locale)/cart/edit(.:format)                     carts#edit {:locale=>/en|sr/}
                     user_cart GET        (/:locale)/cart(.:format)                          carts#show {:locale=>/en|sr/}`

Comment: you are using "resource" for the route and not "resources", "resource" is meant for a resource that's not loaded with an ID but with another method, maybe current_user.cart? since a user will always have one cart and always the same, am I right? check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources for more info about singular resources, that's why you don't have an id, your route is not using ids